# How to move geojson polygon in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Say I have a geojson box I've added to leaflet. How can I allow the user to "click and drag the box" to a new location, which in turn updates all the coordinates automatically? I know how to edit the boundary/points that make up the shape using leaflet editing, but am not sure how to actually move the shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Leaflet.Draw.Drag plugin](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.draw.drag) for Leaflet Draw that allows you to move polygons when you enter edit mode. It does seem to be a bit finicky about the version, though. At least in a few quick experiments, I was only able to get it to work using [Leaflet Draw version 0.2.3](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/0.2.3). If you have an existing L.GeoJson layer, you can simply specify that as the `featureGroup` in the edit options of the draw control:

```js
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: yourGeoJsonLayer,
    edit: {
      selectedPathOptions: {
        maintainColor: true,
        moveMarkers: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In the `selectedPathOptions`, the `maintainColor` option just keeps the existing style of the layer while you're editing, and the `moveMarkers` option places a little square marker in the middle of the polygon as a reminder that you can drag the whole thing rather than just edit the vertices.
Here is an example fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/qk5bsgn8/

Comment: '404 - That page doesn't exist.' Thats the reason why you should better provide code using stack Overflow only. :)